# Inheriting a class that conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift

I can not figure out why Xcode playground is crashing, here is my basic setup

```
protocol Shootable {
    func shoot()
}

class BaseMissile: Shootable {

    var damage = 0

    func shoot() {
        println("Pew pew for \(damage) damage")
    }
}

class Missile1: BaseMissile {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        damage = 1
    }

}

protocol Targetable {
    var life: Int {get set}
}

class BaseSpaceship: Targetable {

    var life = 0
    var currentMissile: BaseMissile!

    func printHealth() {
        println("My current life: \(life)")
    }

}

class Spaceship1: BaseSpaceship {


    override init() {
        super.init()
        life = 1
        currentMissile = Missile1()
    }
}

var spaceship = Spaceship1()
spaceship.printHealth()
spaceship.currentMissile.shoot()
```

specifically the last line `spaceship.currentMissile.shot()` crashes the playground. If I move `var currentMissile: BaseMissile!` from `BaseSpaceship` to `Spaceship1` it works, but is that an acceptable way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens because `BaseSpaceship` class has no initializers and `var currentMissile: BaseMissile!` cant be nil. So you either should do it optional by replacing ! with ? or give it a default value.

Comment: Ok, I changed `var currentMissile: BaseMissile!` to `var currentMissile: BaseMissile?` but now when I do `spaceship.currentMissile.shoot()` I need to write `spaceship.currentMissile?.shoot()` Isn't there a way to not always have to write the `?`

Comment: yes, assign a default value in BaseSpaceship, so the compiler knows you are 100% have a missile. You can do it either in init method or inline in class.

Comment: changing `var currentMissile: BaseMissile?` to `var currentMissile = BaseMissile()` produces the same crash as before

Comment: it happens because BaseMissile has no initializers